# How to cut string between two search patterns(including search patterns) from a file?

Tags: linux, shell, unix

I have a file called `applications.txt` which contains the following data :

```
MOB-x01gmobdb2a-PRD-IBG
TDST-AB-x01gtdsdb1a-UAT-CST
ABC-x01gabcdb2a-PRD-CBG
PQR-x01gpqrdb1a-UAT-IBG
XYZA-GZ-x01gxyzdb2a-PRD-TS
UVW-x01guvwdb1a-UAT-IBG
```

The strings in this file contain hostnames which I would like to display as follows :

```
x01gmobdb2a
x01gtdsdb1a
x01gabcdb2a
x01gpqrdb1a
x01gxyzdb2a
x01guvwdb1a
```

Few of the above servers are UAT and few are PROD servers. As you see the host-names are sandwiched between two patterns:

1. First pattern is `-x` (lowercase x only),
2. Second pattern is either `-UAT` or `-PRD`. Whatever the string available in between first pattern and second pattern, we need to display.

**note:** From the first pattern `x` also should display in output. Example host name is: `x01gmobdb2a`

Comment: Where is your code ? How did you try this ?

Comment: _From the first pattern x also should display in output_ convinces me he has tried...

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. Please show your code. Since Stack Overflow hides the Close reason from you: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/).*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One using awk:

```
$ awk 'match($0,/-x[^-]*/){print substr($0,RSTART+1,RLENGTH-1)}' file
x01gmobdb2a
x01gtdsdb1a
x01gabcdb2a
x01gpqrdb1a
x01gxyzdb2a
x01guvwdb1a
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be your solution. But with out the x pattern. I chose only PRD and UAT.

```
cat applications.txt | grep -e PRD -e UAT |awk -F"-" '{print $(NF-2)}'
```

Comment: Wouldn't `awk -F"-" '{print $(NF-2)}' file` suffice?

Comment: yes james, you are right. But I thought what if there are other server names with DEV or TST unlike PRD and UAT

Comment: In that case: `awk -F"-" '$(NF-1)~"^(UAT|PRD)$"{print NR,$(NF-2)}' file`

Comment: Thank you very much for your time Vignesh. This one also working for me. But when my hostname starts with X(uppercase), above command displaying that hostname also in output.